# Index manager in search

Tags: people-search, managed-property, crawled-property

I want to get the manager of the user in the refinement panel. I already got department there but with manager i have a problem. I isn't even indexed on a full crawl.

I use the Fast Search Tool to query the search. 
Steps I done sp far:
1. Add Userprofiles to Computer (Computer Management -> No AD (Standalone Installation))
2. Created Userprofiles -> Set Values for manager
3. Created a Managed Property "Manager" which is mapped to "People:Manager(Text)" and "ows_Manager(Text)" which both are set to include in index
4. Full Crawl and event Index Reset and then full crawl

So far I have "There are zero documents in the index using this property." in the crawled properties.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, got it. I forgot to set the User Property "Manager" in Userprofile to indexed.

Comment: Awesome... it worked for me...

Comment: Thanks Steffen. You saved me a few hours of figuring out why the property wasn't returning anything! If I ever see you, I owe you a beer!